# "Is it in slang?" versus "is it slang?"

Tags: phrases, prepositions

What is more correct and why? I heard few British people speaking "in slang" and some of them said that unofficial language is named "slang."

Additionally, is "slang" official/polite word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Slang* is a type of language rather than a language in itself, so one would ideally say that someone was *using slang*. *'Speaking in slang'* is not really correct. *'Is it slang?'* would be better, but to play it safe you might say *'is it an example of slang?'*

A closely related term is the noun '**colloquialism**', the adjectival form being **colloquial**. You would say:

> *He used colloquial terms.*
>
> *The term is a colloquialism.*

Addendum: as colloquial language generally comprises relaxed grammar rather than a set of informal words, the terms are not necessarily interchangeable--as kiamlaluno rightly pointed out below.

Comment: _Slang_ is not a less formal term; in fact, the word is used from the dictionaries when describing a word. There is a difference between _slang_ and _colloquialism_; _wheels_ can be used as slag for _car_, but it is not a colloquial term.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I agree that there is a distinction between an informal lexicon and a relaxed grammar. I spoke imprecisely and I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: "_Wheels_ can be used as slag for _car_" was supposed to be "_wheels_ can be used as slang for _car_."

Comment: Ha, yes I guessed; it is unfortunate that there is not a 'one character edit' privilege even for someone of your reputation level.

Comment: If I had noticed the typo in the five minutes timeframe, I could have edited the comment; after 5 minutes the comments are not editable anymore. It's not a matter of editing a single character, which is always allowed to whom has the privilege of editing any posts. It's just a matter of my attention level. `:-)`

Comment: Ah, I see. I must have misunderstood something I read on meta about single character edits. Anyway, I should stop talking now. Thanks again.